# Validate Parameters Azure APIM Policy is not working as expected for URL path parameters

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have azure HTTP trigger function with route defined

```
public async Task<IActionResult> FetchUser(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "v1/users/{profileid}")]
            HttpRequest req,
            string profileid)
```

APIM URL : https://sampleapidemo-apim-poc.azure-api.net/v1/users/PROFILEIDTOBEENTER

I had imported azure function app in APIM and trying to create a inbound policy to check whether profile id in url path parameter is provided or not.

I tried below 2 ways.

```
<validate-parameters specified-parameter-action="prevent" unspecified-parameter-action="prevent" errors-variable-name="requestUrlValidation">
            <path specified-parameter-action="prevent">
                <parameter name="profileid" action="prevent" />
            </path>
        </validate-parameters>
```

```
<set-variable name="profileParameter" value="@(context.Request.Url.Path.Contains("profileid"))" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@((bool)context.Variables["profileParameter"] == false)">
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="400" reason="Bad Request" />
                    <set-body>
<value>Profile Id is missing in url path.</value></set-body>
                </return-response>
            </when>
            <otherwise />
        </choose>
```

**Actual Output:**
When hitting URL `https://sampleapidemo-apim-poc.azure-api.net/v1/users/` or `https://sampleapidemo-apim-poc.azure-api.net/v1/users`

```
{
    "statusCode": 404,
    "message": "Resource not found"
}
```

**Expected Output:**
When hitting URL `https://sampleapidemo-apim-poc.azure-api.net/v1/users/` or `https://sampleapidemo-apim-poc.azure-api.net/v1/users`

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": "Bad Request. Profile ID is missing in URL path"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined {profileid} as a template parameter in your APIM URL it cannot be omitted. APIM does not recognize the URL if the {profileid} is blank. Hence, the error 404. If you use query parameters instead it will probably work:

Instead of doing:
[https://sampleapidemo-apim-poc.azure-api.net/v1/users/{profileid}](https://sampleapidemo-apim-poc.azure-api.net/v1/users/%7Bprofileid%7D)

You can do this: https://sampleapidemo-apim-poc.azure-api.net/v1/users

Query parameter:

profileid

Result:
[https://sampleapidemo-apim-poc.azure-api.net/v1/users?profileid={profileid}](https://sampleapidemo-apim-poc.azure-api.net/v1/users?profileid=%7Bprofileid%7D)

You can fetch the parameter value in your Azure function like this:

```
string profileid= req.Query["profileid"];
```